# Pinescript - "Compare" Indicator with Percentage Change Function takes only last bar data

Tags: compare, percentage, indicator

need help pls.

In Tradingview I use "Compare" to see the BTCUSDT vs. ETHUSDT on Binance and it's basically OK. But lines on the chart are too "up & down" and I want to see the SMA or EMA for those tickers.

I'm trying to do it step by step but I can't pass through the issue that my code takes only last calculated value in consideration and "percentage change line" starts from 0 with each new data. So it makes no sence. Meaning, my last data doesn't add upon prior value, but always starts from zero.

So, data (value) that comes out is good (same as when I put same tickers on Tradingview "Compare") but Tradingview "Compare" calculates / adds data on historical data, while my code starts from 0.

Here is the Pine script code:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Compare", shorttitle="Compare", overlay=false, max_bars_back=0)

perc_change = (((close[0] - open[0]) / open [0]) * 100)

sym1 = "BINANCE:BTCUSDT", res1 = "30", source1 = perc_change

plot(security(sym1, res1, source1), color=color.orange, linewidth=2)


sym2 = "BINANCE:ETHUSDT", res2 = "30", source2 = perc_change

plot(security(sym2, res2, source2), color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, please simplify your question. Also make use of formatting code as code, that will make it easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the delta between the two ROCs is what you are looking for. With this you can show only the 2 ROCs, but also columns representing the delta between the two. you can also change the ROC's period:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Compare", shorttitle="Compare")
rocPeriod = input(1, minval = 1)
showLines = input(true)
showDelta = input(true)

perc_change = roc(close, rocPeriod)
sym1 = "BINANCE:BTCUSDT"
sym2 = "BINANCE:ETHUSDT"
res = "30"

s1 = security(sym1, res, perc_change)
s2 = security(sym2, res, perc_change)
delta = s1 - s2
plot(showLines ? s1 : na, "s1", color.orange)
plot(showLines ? s2 : na, "s2", color.blue)
hline(0)
plot(showDelta ? delta : na, "delta", delta > 0 ? color.lime : color.red, 1, plot.style_columns)
```

[image]